# Spatial datatypes, Entity Framework 5 and SqlCompact not working

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using EF5.0 together with EntityFramework.SqlCompact (4.3.3). When I am trying to create a simple unit test I get the error:

System.NotSupportedException: There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.Geography(Nullable=True)' of primitive type 'Geography'.

Without the Geography attribute everything runs fine.

Comment: As the man says: You cannot store geography data in SQL Server Compact (but image data type is supported)

Answer (score 0):

@ErikEJ

Sorry, this should be a comment and not an answer, but "the man" clearly does say that you can store geography data in SQL CE:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/eb0f24ba-f705-4ee8-a0b0-40074f133f90/

This seems to be a shortcoming in EF5, not SQL CE.  I'm getting the exact same error using SQL CE 4.0.

Comment: This applies to Merge replication only (I know that it is not clear), and the Geo columns will become image columns in the SQL CE database